# addCoordinatedAnimations animation block not running

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tvos

In tvOS on Xcode 7.3.1, one of the places I use UIFocusAnimationCoordinator's addCoordinatedAnimations function is running the completion before the animation:

```
if (coordinator != nil) {
    var tempDidAnimate: Bool = false  // breakpoint 1
    coordinator!.addCoordinatedAnimations({
        self.myFunctionThatDoesntGetCalled() // breakpoint 2
        tempDidAnimate = true
        }, completion: {
            () in
            if tempDidAnimate == false {
                print("whaaaat?!??")  // breakpoint 3
                self.myFunctionThatDoesntGetCalled()                        
            }
    })
}
```

Order of breakpoints being hit is 1, 3. Never 2.

This hacky use of `if tempDidAnimate == false` does solve the problem, but I don't get why the problem is happening.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

One idea: I'm already inside an addCoordinatedAnimations block in the stack... I don't think so, but the stack is complicated... can't see any way to check that via code.

Comment: Where are you adding this? Custom focus animations should be added to `didUpdateFocusInContext` which has `coordinator` parameter which is not optional.

Comment: I'm starting in didUpdateFocusInContext, and then calling deep into several levels of blocks and selectors/functions.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: YES I was already inside an animation block #$&^@#$!

Ok, turned out that in my "cleverly" refactored code, I was forgetting that I'm calling an animation block to reset any currently active autolayout animations (by requesting a new animation with duration 0). Then in that completion, my code above is being called... Since I'm officially already inside an animation block, the OS refuses to execute the main animation block above, and skips right to the completion. Don't know if this OS behavior is documented anywhere.